# Lightsail Bitnami - Error establishing a database connection

Tags: mysql, wordpress, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I have a WordPress website hosted by AWS Lightsail.

When I access my website, I got this error - `Error establishing a database connection`

I didn't change anything for the last few days, and it was working okay.

Also, I have two snapshots and tried to restore the instance, but I got same error messages.

I tried to fix it by adding `define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);` line in my wp-config.php file, but it's not working.

I tried to access mysql on the terminal by following the command `mysql -u root -p` and typed password that I got from `cat bitnami_application_password`, but I got this error message - `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local server through socket '/opt/bitnami/mariadb/tmp /mysql.sock' (111)`

`$ ps -ef | grep mysql`
`bitnami   3483   802  0 15:17 pts/0    00:00:00 grep mysql`

If I run `df -h`, I got this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            989M     0  989M   0% /dev
tmpfs           200M  2.9M  197M   2% /run
/dev/xvda1       59G  8.6G   48G  16% /
tmpfs           998M     0  998M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           998M     0  998M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda15     124M  278K  124M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           200M     0  200M   0% /run/user/1000
```

If I run `sudo service mysql stop`, I got this error message:
`Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.`

If I run `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status`, I got this message:

```
Cannot find any running daemon to contact. If it is running, make sure you are pointing to the right pid file (/var/run/gonit.pid)
```

Comment: Brandon, did you find the solution this?

Comment: @MehulKaklotar No. I had to build the entire website again. I hired 4~5 freelancers to fix this issue, but no one was able to fix it.

Comment: Yeah, the Lightsail instance has its limitations around how much it can handle. a normal WP site with few plugins will be handled by it but it can't handle medium to heavy load sites. I need to move my instance to EC2 and RDS for db to handle it.